# Sql multiple joins to same table both inclusive and exclusive

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table Foo

```
FOO
-------
id
name

BAR
-------
id
name

FOO_BAR_XREF
-------
foo_id
bar_id
```

I need to select all instances of FOO where foo.id has a record in foo_bar_xref with a bar_id of 1 and exclude records from foo where foo.id has a record n foo_bar_xref with a bar_id of 2

foo -> foo_bar_xref is one to many *emphasized text*foo_bar_xref may contain multiple bar_id's per foo_id

Is this possible with only joins or do I need to use not exists statements in the where clause?

so far I have

```
select f.name from FOO f
inner join FOO_BAR_XREF fb_1 on fb_1.foo_id = f.id
inner join FOO_BAR_XREF fb_2 on fb_2.foo_id = f.id

where fb_1.bar_id = 1 and fb_2.bar_id <> 2
group by f.name -- remove dupes - running on sql server and is paged with sql servers hackish over keyword where distinct doesn't work so well.
```

thats not filtering out the foo's that have a bar of 2

THIS seems to work but I'm not sure it's the most efficient

```
select f.name from FOO f
inner join FOO_BAR_XREF fb_1 on fb_1.foo_id = f.id and fb_1.bar_id = 1
left outer join FOO_BAR_XREF fb_2 on fb_2.foo_id = f.id and fb_2.bar_id = 2

where fb_2.bar_id is null
group by f.name -- remove dupes
```

Comment: I like your left join approach -- my thoughts as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reiterate my comment, I think OP has best solution.  I have always preffered using left joins for these scenarios.

```
select f.name 
from FOO f 
inner join FOO_BAR_XREF fb_1 
  on fb_1.foo_id = f.id and fb_1.bar_id = 1 
left outer join FOO_BAR_XREF fb_2 
  on fb_2.foo_id = f.id 
  and fb_2.bar_id = 2
where fb_2.bar_id is null
group by f.name
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4cbb7/1).

BTW, I think this is the most efficient solution in regards to table scans.  Check your execution plans and see what you have going on.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to select all instances of FOO where foo.id has a record in
>   foo_bar_xref with a bar_id of 1 and exclude records from foo where
>   foo.id has a record n foo_bar_xref with a bar_id of 2

Since you are using SQL Server, you can use the `EXCEPT` set operation to do so like this:

```
SELECT f.id, f.name 
FROM FOO f
INNER JOIN FOO_BAR_XREF fb_1 ON fb_1.foo_id = f.id
WHERE fb_1.bar_id = 1
EXCEPT 
SELECT f.id, f.name from FOO f
INNER JOIN FOO_BAR_XREF fb_1 ON fb_1.foo_id = f.id
WHERE fb_1.bar_id = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is one way to do this.  It summarizes the xref table to get the foo's with bar=1 but not bar=2.  I prefer using aggregation for this type of query, in general.

```
select f.*
from foo f join
     (select f.foo_id
      from foo_bar_xref
      group by f.foo_id
      having max(case when bar_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and -- has 1 bar
             max(case when bar_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) = 0     -- no 2 bar
    ) fbx
    on f.id = fbx.foo_id
```

Note: this SQL is not tested so it may have syntax errors.

Comment: is the subselect any more or less efficient than the inner/left join combo that I have working?

Comment: @dstarh . . . The only way to really answer that question is to compare actual execution plans.  This method scans the xref table, groups it (probably using a hash group algorithm) and then joins to foo.  Your method requires two joins to the larger table, followed by a group by.  It is quite possible that this method is faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from foo join (
select foo_id from FOO_BAR_XREF where bar_id =1
except
select foo_id from FOO_BAR_XREF where bar_id =2
) X on id=foo_id
```